# Magento Request - Frontend, Backend or API?

Tags: web-services, api, events, magento

OK - I've read and like the discussion on Magento frontend/backend and agree with Ben's answer
in [Magento Request - Frontend or Backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693020/magento-request-frontend-or-backend)

Now let's take it up a notch.  We have a customer with a highly customized solution where we use a Magento observer to call a webservice that updates customer and customer address data in a corporate CRM system. These events hang off of the customer_save_before, customeraddress_save_before events and have slightly different calls on the frontend and adminhtml sides (thanks Ben!).

Now we're seeing a looping situation starting up where the CRM system is using the Magento API to insert updates into Magento, which fires the customer_save_before event and we then send the data back to the CRM - which then calls the Magento API again, etc, etc, etc until the whole house-o-cards comes tumbling down.

I'd like to be able to mask out the inbound API calls, but, I can't find any information about how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the block whos called the event. Try it:

```
$block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Your_block_name) {
//do something
```

Or, you can change mage core code, to when dispatch the event send some additional data for your control.
Like that:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_save_before',array('flag'=>'1'));
```

Or something like that. 
But, if this event its called aways from the same place by the same block and dont have any other behavior to know when its called by magento or by the webservice, so its impossible.

Comment: The problem is the API calls also dispatch events. I'll look at the block suggestion.  There should not be a block associated with an API call.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my previous answer - the formdata detection worked OK, but, I think this will work even better -

Look at the request_uri and see of the api has been called.

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "index.php/api")) {
   $ApiCall=true;
}
```

If so then set a flag or do whatever.